# Sync an attribute from ADFS to Azure AD custom application

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, adfs

I have an Azure AD Tenant that is federated with ADFS. 
ADFS has an attribute called "employeeNumber".

When a user authenticates against AAD for accessing our custom Web API, i would like the jwt provided by AAD to contain the claim "employeeNumber".
Once the user is authenticated against the custom Web API, the code must check the presence of this claim and its related value.

I've found some tutorials for doing something like this but they refers to SaaS applications.
[Attribute sync tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/user-provisioning-sync-attributes-for-mapping)

Custom applications registered in AAD don't have the option "provisioning" that the above link refers to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using AAD Connect?

That needs to be configured to pass the attribute.

Then you need to tell Azure AD to pass the attribute by [modifying the manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims).

Comment: Yes i'm using AAD Connect. I read the tutorial about configuring aad connect to pass the attribute. Then i suppose that i've to modify the app's manifest file. The link you provided talks about "optional" claims that seem to be part of a predefined set. How can (and can i...?) i insert a custom claim that comes from ADFS? Is there any example?